# How to update Mongoose schema? New changes not reflected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model.js is as follows:

```
const transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    expiryDate: {
        type: Date,
        // default: () => new Date(+new Date() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
        default: () => new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)),
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema)

Transaction.collection.dropIndex('_id_', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error in dropping index!', err);
    }
});

module.exports = Transaction
```

I am trying to change the `default` property from the commented line of code to the new default line of code.

Understand that I'll have to `dropIndex` for this new property to take effect. However, Mongo is not allowing me to drop `_id`.

How can I update my schema based on the new changes?

Comment: "Understand that I'll have to dropIndex for this new property to take effect" - why?

Comment: @AlexBlex based on what I've googled because I've tried doing it without dropIndex but the changes on the schema were not reflected in the database.

Comment: "based on what I've googled " - mind explaining? we don't have history of your google searches. You don't need to drop index to change shape of the document, so I believe it's misunderstanding. It makes no sense without context, hence the question - where did you read that indexes must be dropped. Especially the system's  _id

Comment: In fact, you don't even change shape of the document, you change only default value, which is a clientside javascript.